# Error when parsing graph_def from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run a very simple saving of a Tensorflow graph as .pb file, but I have this error when parsing it back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_import_stripped_bm.py", line 28, in <module>
    graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 185, in ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1069, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1105, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 633, in DecodeField
    if value._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1105, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 612, in DecodeRepeatedField
    if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1105, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 743, in DecodeMap
    if submsg._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1095, in InternalParse
    new_pos = local_SkipField(buffer, new_pos, end, tag_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 850, in SkipField
    return WIRETYPE_TO_SKIPPER[wire_type](buffer, pos, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 799, in _SkipGroup
    new_pos = SkipField(buffer, pos, end, tag_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 850, in SkipField
    return WIRETYPE_TO_SKIPPER[wire_type](buffer, pos, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 814, in _SkipFixed32
    raise _DecodeError('Truncated message.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message.
```

This is the code that I use to write it to .pb:

```
import tensorflow as tf

builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('models/TEST-3')

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((2,2)), name="w1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((2,2)), name="w2")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], clear_devices = True)

builder.save()
sess.close()
```

And this is the code to parse it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

model_path = os.path.join('models/TEST-3', 'saved_model.pb')
with open(model_path, mode='rb') as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)
```

To see the exact error I had to do

```
export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python
```

before running it.
Also I've tried this on python 2 and 3 with different tensorflow versions, I am running on Ubuntu 16.04. On python 2.7 with tensorflow 0.9.0rc0 I managed to get a slightly different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 185, in ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1091, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1127, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 633, in DecodeField
    if value._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1127, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 612, in DecodeRepeatedField
    if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1127, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 612, in DecodeRepeatedField
    if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1127, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 489, in DecodeRepeatedField
    value.append(_ConvertToUnicode(buffer[pos:new_pos]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 469, in _ConvertToUnicode
    return local_unicode(byte_str, 'utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 18: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 18: invalid start byte in field: tensorflow.FunctionDef.Node.ret
```

I am able to parse other .pb graph with this code for example this one https://github.com/taey16/tf/blob/master/imagenet/classify_image_graph_def.pb

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to parse a [`SavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/635196732151e6d8638c189c52f4c4336ede81b6/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto) protocol buffer as if it were a [`GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/635196732151e6d8638c189c52f4c4336ede81b6/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto). Although a `SavedModel` contains `GraphDef`, they have different binary formats. The following code, using [`tf.saved_model.loader.load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader/load) should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "models/TEST-3")
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to get a serialized GraphDef which I managed to do with:
sess.graph_def.SerializeToString() and then loaded it with:
`graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(graph_string)
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name=”)` since I need to load it like that. Problem now is that variables are not initialized.
I want to use the model in Spark and am following this guide https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/25/deep-learning-with-apache-spark-and-tensorflow.html

Comment: The `GraphDef` on its own doesn't provide enough information to initialize the variables. That tutorial is quite out of date... it pre-dates `SavedModel`, which makes doing this kind of thing much easier. it should be enough to load the `SavedModel` with the command in my answer, because it will initialize your variables for you.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but now problem is that is is very slow since it reads it from disc every time since I run that in different processes and I cannot reuse the same tf session. Is there a way to load the SavedModel from a string instead of reading it from the directory ? Or maybe in some other way?

Comment: If you take a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/84e00bf64d89b8b39fe3b82fa305ee13b2a5613b/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py#L58), you might be able to extract the code that parses the `SavedModel` proto and run it once to get a `GraphDef`. (However, it would be difficult to make the checkpoint-loading code work across different sessions, because the `Saver` implementation is inherently file-based.)

Answer (score 1):

```
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)
```

Here fileContent should be a **"Frozen Graph". Tensorflow provides an api for the same as well, refer [Tensorflow freeze_graph API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

Another way to create frozen graph is:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
      saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(<.meta file>)
      saver.restore(sess, <checkpoint>)
      output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                    sess,
                    tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(),
                    [comma separated output nodes name]
                ) 
      # Saving "output_graph_def " in a file and generate frozen graph.
      with tf.gfile.GFile('frozen_graph.pb', "wb") as f:
      f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Use frozen_graph.pb as

```
graph_def.ParseFromString("frozen_graph.pb")
```

So first using **Saver** object generates the .meta and other files. Once its done create frozen graph.

Comment: your approach graph_def.ParseFromString(filepath) raises TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'