# Tensorflow: error trying to restore a model in a pb file

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, resnet

I'm trying to load an already trained model taken from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet, but when  I try to load the `.pb` I get an error on `ParseFromString` method:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
GRAPH_PB_PATH = '../resnet_v2_fp32_savedmodel_NHWC/1538687283/saved_model.pb'
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
sess = tf.Session(graph=g_in)

DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

What I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, instead of using gfile I use the tf.saved_model.loader.load function like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547595/4637693:

```
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], './model')
graph_def = model.graph_def
```